# Picasso is showing wrong image when file does not exists on local storage

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I've a recycler view which shows list of users with their avatar. After login I download all avatar and save them locally with the file name which is user's row id from mongo db. When the avatar file is not available in storage Picasso loads one of other user's avatar at random. What should I do prevent this. 
This is common code for showing or downloading image in case of unavailability

I tried using cache policies in Picasso but that didn't work either.

```java
public ImageUtils loadFromDisk(String id, ImageView target) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadFromDisk: imageId: " + id);
        File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("avatars", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File avatarPath = new File(directory, id);
        if (avatarPath.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "loadFromDisk: loaded from disk" + avatarPath);
            Picasso.get().load(avatarPath)
                    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                    .into(target);
        } else {
           Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.image_thumb).into(target);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

I call loadFromDisk from a Singleton ImageUtils class in RecyclerView bindView holder class.

PS: bindViewHolder code

```java
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecentChatsViewHolder recentChatsViewHolder, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: content row");

        if (recentChat.isNew) {
            recentChatsViewHolder.blueDot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recentChatsViewHolder.blueDot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        recentChatsViewHolder.avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_white_48dp);
        ImageUtils.getInstance(context).loadFromDisk(recentChat.id, recentChatsViewHolder.avatar); //this calls above function here I don't pass the else condition of above method so there's no race condition 

    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the RecyclerView's Adapter and ViewHolder as well?

Comment: Added requested code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is inside a recyclerView, I am assuming there's some kind of race condition happening. When you call `FileDownloader` to download some image. It downloads the image and the loads it to the target. But the target is not correct since the recycler view is now scrolled.

Maybe, you could avoid this by adding `id` as a tag to the `ImageView` and check the tag once the image is downloaded. If the tag is different, don't load the image into the view. -> This would only work if the download callback/lambda passes the `id`.

EDIT:

I don't know what's happening with `fallback`. It would be better if you could remove it from the snippet you have added.

I can suggest 2 things.

1. `ImageView.setImageBitmap(null)` or ask Picasso to clear the target before loading a new image. If the avatar doesn't exist, clear the target.
2. Add `errorDrawable` so if there's an error, it won't show the previous image.

Comment: Added some code. The file downloader is only used when there's a fallback url passed but in this case I don't pass any fallback url so that doesn't execute so I think there's no race condition here @Froyo

Comment: By default loadImageFromDisk will load an image from storage but in case it's not available and I passed a url while calling loadImageFromDisk then it should load image from URL and also downloader will make it available for next time. That's why I used a fallback url. @froyo

Comment: But the downloader has a callback `loadFromDisk(id, target);` which will load the image to the target.

Comment: It won't since it only executes if fallback url passed but see the bindViewHolder code it's not passed so the second else will execute

Comment: So since it's not related to the question, can you remove it from the snippet?

Comment: Removed it @froyo

Comment: Adding error placeholder and cancelling request before loading the new url worked @froyo. Thanks